# Continuity of $x - y\lceil \frac{x}{y} \rceil$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, modular-arithmetic

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$f(x,y) = x - y\lceil \frac{x}{y} \rceil$.

$g(x,y) = (x-y\lceil\frac{x}{y}\rceil) - (y - x\lceil\frac{y}{x}\rceil)\lceil {\frac{(x-y\lceil\frac{x}{y}\rceil)}{(y - x\lceil\frac{y}{x}\rceil)}}\rceil$

I am trying to determine where the functions $f,g$ are continuous.  I suspect both are nowhere continuous (see my answer below.)

Comment: What are the domain and codomain?

Comment: You shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax like that.  You get misalignments, mismatches in fonts and font sizes, and lack of proper spacing.  Look at my edits to your question. $\qquad$

Comment: Both $f$ and $g$ are functions from R^2 into R

Comment: Then what does $\;x\pmod \pi\;$ mean in the real realm?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry I'm still learning how to format things properly

Comment: @Joanpemo x mod y just means remainder when x is divided by y, ie $55 \bmod \pi = 55-17\pi$, about 1.592

Comment: The remainder in the real numbers? Zero always, of course. It is interesting in $\;\Bbb Z\;$, though.

Comment: @Joanpemo Why would we always get remainder $0$ in the real number

Comment: Because any real number is divisible into any other non-zero real number.

Comment: I suppose what I really mean is $x \bmod y$ $=$ $x - integer part of x/y$.

Comment: One application of this, albeit not a very interesting one, is evaluating the trigonometric functions for very large arguments

Comment: Start by graphing $x \mod 1$ and deciding where it is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are nowhere continuous.

Consider the function $h(x,y) = x \bmod y$ for a fixed real number $y$, where $x \bmod y$ is evaluated as $x - y\lceil x/y \rceil.$  The function $h$ is discontinuous at every integer multiple of $y$.  The function $f$ includes all of these as special cases so is nowhere continuous.

The function $g(x,y) = (x \bmod y) \bmod (y \bmod x)$ is really just a composition of nowhere continuous functions, namely $g(x,y) = f(f(x,y),f(y,x))$ so $g$ is nowhere continuous.